# Unknown Member error foxpro

Tags: foxpro

I'm getting Unknown member CLCHRISID error in grid. I check the grid in that column is exist. I trying searching for possible solution for this error in internet but still no luck.

[image: Error]

[image]

Comment: An error like that without a code line referenced suggests a problem in the Property Sheet. Check over the properties in the form. Maybe you're referring to the column before the grid has been initialized?

Comment: Finally solve. I using summaryCA in recordSource but in my recordsourcetype is use the 0. table. when i change the recordsourcetype into 1. Alias it works now. tnbx